# Como enviar email sem uma view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Todos os tutoriais que acho, inclusive na documentação oficial mostram como enviar emails usando views.

Como enviar emails sem nenhuma view? Como rotina do sistema automaticamente?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function email()
{
    Mail::send([], [], function ($message)
    {
        $message->to('email@destinatario.com')
            ->subject('EMAIL TESTE AUTOMÁTICO')
            ->setBody('CORPO DA MENSAGEM DE EMAIL TESTE!!!');
    });
    return "email enviado";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O correto nesse caso seria usar o método `raw` e não o `send`

```
Mail::raw('CORPO DA MENSAGEM DE EMAIL TESTE!!!', function ($message) {
    $message->to('email@destinatario.com')
        ->subject('EMAIL TESTE AUTOMÁTICO')        
});
```

Veja na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail#sending-mail).